# Rails 4: rbenv & rvm clash, following tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

When first started, I installed Rails with rbenv and, through time, created a few apps. I have not had to touch rbenv, never had a problem, yet never had a chance to get to know it.

I recently decided to run through the "Learn Ruby on Rails" tutorial by Daniel Kehoe. In his chapters dealing with installation, he has us download RVM with a project-specific gemset using the following command:

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.1@learn-rails --create
$ gem install rails
```

Will I still be able to download the specific gemset using rbenv instead? If so, what is the command and how would I go about this?

On a side note, are there any great beginner tutorials for using rbenv?

Comment: "is there any great beginner tutorials for using rbenv?". Yes. Read [the instructions](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). It's a very nicely thought out tool that is easy to understand.

Comment: Also, like all programs, rbenv has upgrades. Be sure to periodically run `git pull` from inside ~/.rbenv to pull in changes.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't install RVM and rbenv side-by-side. They can interfere with one another. What I would recommend doing instead is ignoring the RVM + gemset section and continuing on with the guide using rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

Concurring with Ryan Bigg's answer: indeed, see https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation:

`Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv.`

And if you want to use gemsets with rbenv, see https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset